# How Floor and Ceil a value to it's nearest integer in python3.x?

Tags: floor, ceil

If input = 12.00 to 12.49 output = 12
if input = 12.50 to 13.00 output = 13

Answer (score 0):

Try round defined in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

```
round(input, 0)
```

Comment: He is specifically asking about Python 3.x (regarding the link you referred to). Just saying.

Comment: I have updated the link (although no change in behavior I believe...)